# Returning a spark Column from a spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm writing my own custom UDF which takes in a byte array and returns it as an `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, UDFRegistration}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

private final def udf: (Array[Byte]) => Column = {
  
  case (bytes) => 
    // other logic
    lit(bytes)
}

override def register(registration: UDFRegistration): Unit = {
  registration.register("my_udf", udf)
}
```

but this errors out with this exception

```
Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported *** ABORTED ***
```

how do I do this? I looked around for answers but this doesn't seem possible. You may be asking "why not just use lit directly" but there's a bunch of code in here I left out to simplify things

Comment: This is not a UDF. It's just a normal function in Scala that returns a Spark column. You cannot register it as a UDF.

Comment: @mck sorry just made an edit clarifying that. I'm doing some other transformations within the udf, but I created the question with this simple code to get to the point

Comment: My comment remains correct. If you're returning a Column from your function, it cannot be registered as a UDF.

Comment: @mck the input byte array represents some data of a custom class which I'm aiming to deserialize into a spark row so it can be used like any other row after this UDF is called

Comment: @mck * I want it to return a column full of spark rows since the input byte array represents the entire column

Comment: So are you trying to add a new column to an existing dataframe? A join is needed probably.

Comment: @mck no, this is supposed to basically cast my rows of input byte arrays into something that Spark can actually use. For example, if my udf returns a String then a df.show will output ```X'E00100EAEB8183D887B6816181628163DE988A21018B483FF199999999999A8C69800FE58181808080C3'```, but I want it to output the actual spark data, like ```"{ a : 1 }"```

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand. Would you be able to provide a [mcve] to illustrate?